# Deploy a selenium test project in eclipse that uses ant build file to run

Tags: eclipse, ant, selenium-rc

I have a testing project that uses selenium RC and is currently on eclipse. I run the selenium test scripts and generate report using ant build file in eclipse only.

I want to deploy my project in executable file such that i don't need eclipse to run my project. It can be .jar file or .bat file. preferably .bat file; so that i can run it from command line.

Also, in case of bat file, will the other PC executing the executable will need any additional setup?

Is there any plugin for eclipse through which it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was doing something like this.

You should:

- have mozilla executable in your path
- launch java.exe from .bat file this way:

  java.exe -cp ./production/;./lib/* package.MainClass

./production should contain your compiled classes and libs should contain all jars. You may also pack your app into a jar file, this is described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Thanks, this is I am actually doing: <br/> My build file is running the selenium server, the compilation of the files is done next and then the test cases are executed, showing the reports.<br/> I want to do this using a jar or a bat file; so that eclipse is not visible to the client.